# plain html combo box code

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I've searched online and didn't find even one example of a combo box which could be rendered using plain HTML and Javacript.

Is it possible to have a combobox using standard HTML and Javascript? By combo-box, I mean where input is also possible and a drop-down options are also possible - in a single element. I'm not looking for one select box and in addition another input box.

An example of what I'm looking for is:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox

However, I don't want to use any Javascript library like jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

datalist is an `html5` component. This same feature can be created using `input` box and `ul`, `li` elements

```html
<label for="countries">Choose a Country:</label>
<input list="countryList" id="countries" name="countries" />
<datalist id="countryList">
  <option value="India">
  <option value="France">
  <option value="Isreal">
  <option value="USA">
  </datalist>
```

Comment: I agree that he siolution is a datalist - however it should be noted that there is limited browser support for it (eg: Safari does not render it). There is a polyfill that could be used for incompatible browers - just thought it worth mentioning. And also given that its a html5 element -
 the doctype needs to reflect HTML5.That said - the data-list rocks.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it using earlier from another stackoverflow answer. Somehow, it didn't work on IE at my office desktop. However, I see now that it works on Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: @gavgrif thanks for your suggestion. Could you please post a working code snippet as `brk` has done?

Comment: RRM - any suggestion i would make has already been posted by @brk - its the right way to do it - then you just have to account for the older browsers etc - search for datalist polyfill and in clude it in the page.